# Can I get ProjectPermissions from Excel Add-in?

Tags: excel, rally

Would it be possible, using the Excel Add-id, to retrieve the projects for a user?

I only want a specific workspace.  I only care about Editor access.

I tried to add "ProjectPermissions" to my query against the "Workspace Permissions" type.

Thanks in advance,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

Set up the query like this

- Type:  Project Permission
- Order:  It is sort of irrelevant, pick one
- Columns:  Name,Role,Project,Subscription,User
- Filter:  ((Project = "projectnamehere") AND (Role = "Editor"))

You can pick whatever you like in the Columns entry obviously, and as a side note if you type them in you can have them appear in the order you want...whereas the pick list just puts them in alphabetical order.